# Is it possible to create an external attachable overlay network from within a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a service (traefik) which uses an external attachable overlay network to communicate with services on our swarm as a reverse proxy.

Traefik is currently configured entirely within a `docker-compose.yml` file for deployment to our docker swarm.

My question is, is it possible to create the external attachable overlay network from within the docker-compose file also the same time?

Currently I have to create this manually prior to deploying the service, using

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable traefik-net
```

Then the relevant parts of my docker-compose.yml look like:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:v2.6
...
networks:
    default:
        name: traefik-net
        driver: overlay
        attachable: true
        external: true
```

I naively hoped that if `traefik-net` didn't exist then it would be created but that doesn't seem to be the case, if I remove the `external: true` then it does create the network but the name is prefixed by the name of the stack provided when I deploy it. Is there some syntax I'm missing or is this just not possible?

Cheers

Rich

Comment: You told compose the network is external, so it shouldn't be created.

Comment: Ah yes, @BMitch, sorry I wasn't too clear on that, if I don't mark it as external then it does create it but prefixed by the stack name (will update the question).

Comment: The Compose file v3 format specifies that a custom [`name:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#name-1) is not prefixed with the Compose project name; so that `name:` without `external:` _should_ get the effect you want.  Are you running `docker-compose` with a hyphen or `docker compose` with a space?  (I've seen several other SO questions around apparent bugs in the rebuilt `docker compose` built into the core `docker` tool.)

Comment: I do exactly this, with the omission of `external: true`. As mentioned above explicitly naming something prevents docker attaching a stack name prefix.

Comment: Thank you guys, this is exactly what I was after. I didn't realise this was how it worked.